# What commands are available in Windows 8 Speech Recognition?

Tags: windows-8

Is there a master list of Speech Recognition commands for Windows 8?

Especially for using the newly introduced components like "Charms Bar" etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a list of [common commands for speech recognition in Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/using-speech-recognition) (little change compared to older versions of Windows). From the Microsoft Windows Support page:

```
To do this                              Say this
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select any item by its name             Click File; Start; View
Select any item or icon                 Click Recycle Bin; Click Computer;
                                        Click file name
Double tap or double-click any item     Double-click Recycle Bin;
                                        Double-click Computer;
                                        Double-click file name
Switch to an open app                   Switch to Paint; Switch to WordPad;
                                        Switch to program name;
                                        Switch application
Scroll in one direction                 Scroll up; Scroll down;
                                        Scroll left; Scroll right
Insert new paragraph/line in a document New paragraph; New line
Select a word in a document             Select word
Select a word and start to correct it   Correct word
Select and delete specific words        Delete word
Show a list of applicable commands      What can I say?
Update speech commands available        Refresh speech commands
Turn on listening mode                  Start listening
Turn off listening mode                 Stop listening
Move Speech Recognition microphone bar  Move speech recognition
Minimize the microphone bar             Minimize speech recognition
View Help/Support about specific tasks  How do I do something?
                                        For example,
                                        say “How do I install a printer?”
```

In particular, the commands available depends on the context (application currently active), so just remember that you can ask **"What can I say?"** at any time to get the commands that are available.